# HTML 5 drawing line doesn't work

Tags: html, canvas, line

I have already searched this site and many others for an answer to this question, but according to every site (including this one and w3schools) the following should work to draw a line using canvas in HTML5.

```
var c=document.getElementById("drawBox");

var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle=document.getElementById("lineColor").value;

ctx.fillStyle=document.getElementById("fillColor").value;

ctx.lineWidth=document.getElementById("lineWidth").value;

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);

ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

ctx.stroke();
```

Keep in mind the above lines are snippets from my code, not the full code itself, that is below.

I am trying to write a simple drawing program for an assignment I have, but for some reason (and I have tested different ways of doing this) it simply won't draw the line.  It's not throwing any errors, it just won't draw the line. I am using Google Chrome (the only browser you can thoroughly trust using html5, to my understanding). I have tested the code below so as to ensure that the logical branches are, in fact, being executed.  In fact, everything is executed perfectly, up until the actual ctx.stroke(); function. Again, it doesn't error, but it simply won't draw the line. The mouseup and mouseout functions are also working fine, as I tested it with other code that I knew would work.  Below is the code I am working with:

HERE IS THE REVISED CODE (STILL DOESN'T DRAW THOUGH, DESPITE ALL THE GOOD HELP SO FAR)

---

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
///////////////////////////////////////////

    var c=document.getElementById("drawBox");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var x=0;
    var y=0;
    var position="";
    var rangeValue=1;
    var x1=0;
    var y1=0;
    var startDraw=false;
    var x2=0;
    var y2=0;


   $('#drawBox').mousemove(function (){
        x=window.event.clientX;
        y=window.event.clientY;

        position=x + ", " + y;

        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML=position;
    });

   $("#lineWidth").mousemove(function (){
   rangeValue = document.getElementById("lineWidth").value;
   $("#rangeValueContainer").html(rangeValue);
  });

  $("#drawBox").mouseout(function (){
     startDraw=false;
  });

   $("#drawBox").mousedown(function (){
        startDraw=true;
        x1=window.event.clientX;
        y1=window.event.clientY;
        ctx.strokeStyle=document.getElementById("lineColor").value;
        ctx.fillStyle=document.getElementById("fillColor").value;
        ctx.lineWidth=document.getElementById("lineWidth").value;
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        });
        ///
    $("#drawBox").mouseup(function (){
           if (startDraw)
           {
                x2=window.event.clientX;
                y2=window.event.clientY;
                //$("p").html(document.getElementById("fillColor").value);
                ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                ctx.stroke();
                startDraw = false;
           }
    });

            ///

        /*if (document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value == "line")
        {
            $("#drawBox").mouseup(function (){
                x2=window.event.clientX;
                y2=window.event.clientY;
                //$("p").html(document.getElementById("lineColor").value);
                ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                ctx.stroke();
            });
        }

        if (document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value == "square")
        {
            $("p").html(document.getElementById("fillColor").value);
        }

        if (document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value == "circle")
        {

        }
    }); */

    $("#eraseBtn").click(function (){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
        ctx.restore();
    });
});
```

Also, some sites say to use `beginPath()` others say to use `beginPath()` and `closePath()`, while others (namely, w3schools) doesn't say to use either?  Are they necessary? What is their point? Do I need them at all, or under certain circumstances?  I must get this program to draw squares and circles, as well, in the end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this post is a little sloppy, I tried, but this is my first post, and I don't think the part of this site that recognizes that something is code, is picking up jquery.
I had to manually enter a lot of linebreaks just to get it to look as bad as it does XD

Also, it is probably important to mention that I have (as I ALWAYS do before testing) cleared the cache and even always use ctrl+f5 to ignore the cache on load.

Thanks

Okay Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Canvas Drawer</title>
    <base href="index.htm"/>
    <link rel="shrotcut icon" href="/paintbrush.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="_Styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_Operation.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="tableContainer">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                </br>
                <span id="programTitle">
                  Painter 0.0
                </span></br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <canvas id="drawBox">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <span>
                    Cursor Position:
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <span id="checkPosition">
                  <span id="check">0, 0</span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        Draw:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select id="shapeSelect" value="line">
            <option value="line">Line</option>
            <option value="square">Square</option>
            <option value="circle">Circle</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        Select Line Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="color" id="lineColor"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        Select Fill Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="color" id="fillColor"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Line Width:</span></br>
        <input type="range" id="lineWidth" min="1" max="30" value="10"/></br>
        <span id="rangeValueContainer">10</span></br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="eraseBtn" type="button" value="Erase"/>
    </p>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Move all your script under one `$(document).ready()`,

ie,

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var c=document.getElementById("drawBox");
   ...
   $('#drawBox').mousemove(function (){
   ...
   });

   etc.

});
```

By surrounding each code snippet in a separate `function(){}` block you are isolating the variables within them.

It also appears as if your canvas does not have any size. Try setting its size as well,

```
<canvas id="drawBox" width="200px" height="200px">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: You, know, now that you mention it, that does make sense, I will try that.

Comment: Well it helped, but it didn't make canvas operate.  I haven't been getting anymore feedback so, I guess no one else can figure it out either, lol, thanks for the attempt at help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing is correct, but there are two problems -

- You added several separate $(document).ready functions, each with
  separate scope which is why none of your variables survived
- You didn't use the jQuery event object to get the client position -
  see the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)

Here's a working version [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gecfj/)

Comment: I think I believe I did use the jquery even object as shown below:

Comment: I see what you mean, but where does "ev" even come from? Why is it needed, and why would I pass in a variable I not only don't know the value of, but also don't see where or even how it applies.

Comment: Also, thank you for the working version for reference!! You are the man!

Comment: Well, sry, thanks for trying, but that doesn't help.  Also I don't think that's it, because the mousemove function works without passing in the event.

Comment: I tried, but still same thing.  I will revise my code and repost

Comment: Yeah, I tried it like you said, but that didn't help, still won't draw.  (but it did in your example, which is weird...) I don't think that passing in event (wherever it comes from) is what's wrong.

Comment: Well it helped, but it didn't make canvas operate.  I haven't been getting anymore feedback so, I guess no one else can figure it out either, lol, thanks for the attempt at help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes. First of all, never assume that your code is correct. If its not working, your code is obviously not correct. In this case it is not a bug. There are 2 things wrong with your current implementation:

1. Your positioning is way off. I have a sneaking suspicion that your line was not visible as it was being rendered far off of the canvas.
2. You need to use `.beginPath()` and  `.closePath()` this will help prevent unpredictable behavior in your path drawing.

**SOLUTION** The problem is that you are defining the dimensions of your canvas in the css and not the canvas element itself.

**Working solution** http://jsfiddle.net/crbHg/9/